# Bubble Sort with compare method not running

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This is a follow-up to my previous question that I asked yesterday. I wrote a Bubble Sort method that analyzes an array of strings and returns the NUMBER of comparisons that the method has made when ordering the array into alphabetical order (the assignment is to write several types of sorting methods and graph the number of comparisons each one makes, to see which is most efficient).

This is my code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    String[] test_array = {"bill", "phil", "adam"};
    /*
    System.out.println(compare("orange", "boogie"));
    */

    System.out.println(bubbleSort(test_array));
  }

public static int compare(String a, String b)
{
    int len = Math.min (a.length(),b.length());
    // looping through every character. If cha is less than chb, the method returns -1, and so on.
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
        char cha = a.charAt(i);
        char chb = b.charAt(i);
        if (cha < chb) {
            return -1;
        } else if (cha > chb) {
            return 1; 
        }
    }
    // Now we account for the length of the word, since it could be the same word.
    if (a.length() < b.length())
        return -1;
    else if (a.length() > b.length())
        return 1;
    // Seems to be the same String, so return 0. 
    else
        return 0;
}

  public static int bubbleSort(String[] test_array) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    // Variable to track number of comparisons. 
    int compNumber = 0;
    while (swapped == true) { 
      swapped = false;
      for (int i = 1; i < test_array.length; i++) {
        // Tracking the number of comparisons
        compNumber++;

        if (compare(test_array[i-1], test_array[i]) > 0) {
          //Switching the variables by use of a temp variable
          String temp = test_array[i-1];
          test_array[i-1] = test_array[i];
          test_array[i] = temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
        else {
         swapped = true; 
        }
      }
    }
    return compNumber; 
  }
```

So the compare method compares two strings (given by the array) and determines if they are in alphabetical order (returns -1) or not (returns 1), or is the same word (returns 0). Then, the bubble sort method calls upon the compare method to go through the array, and it then makes the switches, while my compNumber variable counts the number of times the loop (therefore the number of comparisons) runs.

It compiles fine, but it unfortunately doesn't stop running and doesn't return anything. I've waited 5 minutes so I've determined that something is wrong, probably with my loops. I can't seem to find an issue, having manipulated the parameters of the loops several times. Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use `String#compareTo()` method to compare strings?

Comment: The assignment does not allow it. Otherwise I would. It's an intro to programming course. So they often do not let us take these shortcuts.

Comment: Obviously the `else {
         swapped = true; 
        }
` is the issue, but even if you put`else {
         swapped = false; 
        }
` it is superfluous, you don't need it.  If you're not setting it to true, it's already set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"swapped" will always be true, hence the while will never end looping.
I think you meant to put swapped = false in the else statement

Comment: Oh shoot! You're right! The method runs correctly now. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the else statement makes the algorithm wrong. Try with the following test array:  
String[] test_array = {"adam","bbba","bbbb", "bbbb", "bbba","bbbd"  };
It will be incorrectly ordered. Remove the else statement and it will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set one of these two `swapped = false`... or else *you will never exit the while loop* `because swapped = true always` ... probably changing the second one makes sense !

```
if (compare(test_array[i-1], test_array[i]) > 0) {
          //Switching the variables by use of a temp variable
          String temp = test_array[i-1];
          test_array[i-1] = test_array[i];
          test_array[i] = temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
        else {
         swapped = true; 
        }
```